# WCF and return Custom collection

Tags: .net, wpf, wcf

How any method of WCF application can return custom collection to calling environment.
please help with sample code.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to define an interface as a ServiceContract and the method that returns the Custom Collection as an OperationContract. I will give you the code in VB.net, bus is very very easy to translate it to c#

```
Imports System.ServiceModel
<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface IClientContract

    <OperationContract()>
    Function GetClientList() As IList(Of POCOClients)

End Interface
```

Here, the IList(of POCOClients) is the custom collection. Then, implement the interface.

```
Public Class ClientContractImplementation
    Implements IClientContract

    Private ClientOp As IClientsOperations

    Sub New()
'I use a IoC container here, but you can make a standar New() at this point'
        ClientOp = BLIoC.Container.Resolve(Of IClientsOperations)()
    End Sub

    Public Function GetClientList() As System.Collections.Generic.IList(Of ServiceLayerContract.POCOClients) Implements ServiceLayerContract.IClientContract.GetClientList

        Return ClientOp.SearchClients()

    End Function
End Class
```

And, then you need to configure the app.config to expose the WCF service, in the Service.ServiceModel section:

```
</endpoint>
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="MEX" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
<host>
  <baseAddresses>
    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:81/Client"/>
  </baseAddresses>
</host>
```

Now, when a client calls to the service, a custom collection of IList(Of POCOClients) (or whatever you want) will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am msitaken, it depends largely on whether you are using *core generated proxies* at the client, or using assembly sharing (using the same code at server and client). With proxies - simply: you can't - they are **just** shallow objects representing the public state. All you have in the mex/wsdl is "a set of items of type X", which the code-gen layer interprets (depending on your condiguration) as `List<T>`, `ObservableCollection<T>`, etc.

If you are using assembly sharing, you should *already* have the correct types at the client, so it should just work - but this is less pure in terms of abstraction. Best avoided on a public API, but fine for internal apps that share a platform.